# A question about Sysoev's extension of Grover's algorithm

Tags: grovers-algorithm

An interesting optimization of Grover's quantum algorithm is discussed in Sysoev's paper:

[Reference paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.6030)

We use the usual notation.  $N = 2^n$ ,  the number of all possible n-bit strings . The oracle  $U_\omega$ can be put in the form

$U_\omega=I - 2  (\vert\omega\rangle\langle\omega \vert )$

$U_\omega$ is a reflection of any vector on the hyperplane orthogonal to $\vert\omega\rangle$

The vector $\vert s \rangle $ and operator $U_s$ are introduced.

$\vert s \rangle = H \vert 0 \rangle^n$ , where H is the n-qubit Hadamard transform.

Operator $U_s$ reflects any vector with respect to $\vert s \rangle$

$U_s = 2\vert s \rangle \langle s \vert - I$

The Grover iteration is $U_{Grover} = U_s U_\omega$

$U_{Grover}$ rotates (at every iteration) the initial vector $\vert s \rangle$ towards the desired vector $\vert\omega\rangle$ by the angle $2\theta$, where $sin\theta =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$

We note that a reflection is expressed by a unitary matrix, so if we know the algebraic form of a vector $\vert\zeta\rangle$ then we can physically construct the quantum circuit that implements the operator $U_\zeta$ which reflects any vector with respect to $\vert\zeta\rangle$ .

We consider then the following modified Grover algorithm,  following  Sysoev,  but not exactly.

***Step 1***

$\vert \zeta_1 \rangle  = U_s U_\omega \vert s \rangle$

Use the constructed  quantum circuit implementing the operator:

$U_{\zeta_1} = 2\vert\zeta_1\rangle\langle\zeta_1\vert - I$

***Step 2***

$\vert \zeta_2 \rangle  = U_{\zeta_1} U_\omega \vert {\zeta_1} \rangle$

Use the constructed  quantum circuit implementing the operator:

$U_{\zeta_2} = 2\vert\zeta_2\rangle\langle\zeta_2\vert - I$

***Step 3***

$\vert \zeta_3 \rangle  = U_{\zeta_2} U_\omega \vert {\zeta_2} \rangle$

Use the constructed  quantum circuit implementing the operator

$U_{\zeta_3} = 2\vert\zeta_3\rangle\langle\zeta_3\vert - I$

................................and so on..........

Step $[log_2 N] $(approximately in a neighborhood of n  where we stop,  see note below).

$\vert \zeta_n \rangle  = U_{\zeta_{n-1}} U_\omega \vert \zeta_{n-1} \rangle$

Measurement and stop.

So at each step, the current vector is reflected on the hyperplane orthogonal to $\vert\omega\rangle$ and then we further reflect this reflection with respect to the current vector itself.

The algorithm rotates the initial vector $\vert s \rangle$ towards the solution following the sequence:

$\theta  , 3\theta, 9\theta , .......3^k \theta$ .....

The optimal stopping time will be in a neighborhood of $[log_2 N]$ steps, so after about n steps. The exact number can be calculated. So we can run the algorithm several times, each time stopping at random after a number of steps  in a neighborhood of  $[log_2 N]$. The probability of getting very close to the target vector $\vert\omega\rangle$ becomes sufficiently  high.

Note that Sysoev wants to construct a universal quantum circuit that would also take as input the vector determining the reflection axis. I don't know if such a quantum circuit can be constructed, it might be impossible.  But we can construct in advance all the quantum circuits implementing the operators  $U_{\zeta_k}$  for $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...., [log_2 N]\}$ and run the quantum algorithm.  If we construct these quantum circuits for N sufficiently large (for a large number n of qubits), then most of the NP complete problems of interest can be solved efficiently, basically in  linear time.  We could also consider other sequences of reflections and axes of reflection,  a lot depends on the arithmetic modulo $[\sqrt N]$  for a chosen N.

**Question**.  Assuming  that eventuality quantum circuits with a large number of qubits will become reliable and feasible,  are there any major flaws in my reasoning, in principle?

In his original paper Grover gives a proof of optimality of his algorithm,  but certain assumptions in his proof of optimality are not satisfied by the algorithm described here. So the question is, could  this exponential speedup of Grover's algorithm be  possible in principle?

**Edit 1** We consider the operator U defined by the relation:

$U(\vert x \rangle , \vert y \rangle  ) = ( \vert x \rangle , U_x \vert y \rangle) $  , where  $U_x \vert y \rangle$ represents the reflection of $\vert y \rangle$  with respect to $\vert x \rangle$

We have then the relations:

$U(\vert s \rangle ,  U_\omega\vert  s \rangle  ) = (\vert s \rangle ,  U_sU_\omega \vert s \rangle) = (\vert s \rangle , \vert \zeta_1 \rangle )$

$U(\vert \zeta_1 \rangle ,  U_\omega\vert  \zeta_1 \rangle  ) = (\vert \zeta_1 \rangle ,  U_{\zeta_1}U_\omega \vert \zeta_1 \rangle) = (\vert \zeta_1 \rangle , \vert \zeta_2 \rangle )$

$U(\vert \zeta_2 \rangle ,  U_\omega\vert  \zeta_2 \rangle  ) = (\vert \zeta_2 \rangle ,  U_{\zeta_2}U_\omega \vert \zeta_2 \rangle) = (\vert \zeta_2 \rangle , \vert \zeta_3 \rangle )$

.......................and so on..........................

$U(\vert \zeta_{n-1} \rangle ,  U_\omega\vert  \zeta_{n-1} \rangle  ) = (\vert \zeta_{n-1} \rangle ,  U_{\zeta_{n-1}}U_\omega \vert \zeta_{n-1} \rangle) = (\vert \zeta_{n-1} \rangle , \vert \zeta_n \rangle )$

That means that we only have to design  one quantum circuit,  associated to the operator U. Note that this Grover-Sysoev  iteration (as I would call it) is a bit more complicated than the original Grover iteration, but in principle possible to implement. Well, we have to be  careful so that this type of iteration doesn't enter into  conflict with  the no - cloning theorem.

Another possibility is the following  (state $\vert s \rangle$ is known):

$U(\vert s \rangle ,  U_\omega\vert  s \rangle  ) = (\vert s \rangle ,  U_sU_\omega \vert s \rangle) = (\vert s \rangle , \vert \xi_1 \rangle )$

$U(\vert \xi_1 \rangle ,  U_\omega\vert  s \rangle  ) = (\vert \xi_1 \rangle ,  U_{\xi_1}U_\omega \vert s \rangle) = (\vert \xi_1 \rangle , \vert \xi_2 \rangle )$

$U(\vert \xi_2 \rangle ,  U_\omega\vert  s \rangle  ) = (\vert \xi_2 \rangle ,  U_{\xi_2}U_\omega \vert s \rangle) = (\vert \xi_2 \rangle , \vert \xi_3 \rangle )$

.......................and so on..........................

$U(\vert \xi_{n-1} \rangle ,  U_\omega\vert  s \rangle  ) = (\vert \xi_{n-1} \rangle ,  U_{\xi_{n-1}}U_\omega \vert s \rangle) = (\vert \xi_{n-1} \rangle , \vert \xi_n \rangle )$

In other words, the vector to be reflected is fixed but the reflection axis is variable (in the original Grover algorithm it's the other way around ).

Anyway, my impression is that the implementation of a quantum algorithm with an exponential speedup (compared to Grover's algorithm ) is possible.  That's what this question is all about.

**Edit 2**. Unfortunately nothing from what  I tried seems to work. You need a quantum circuit that takes as input the vector to be reflected and the vector that represents the reflection axis. The output of the quantum circuit must contain the reflected vector. That does not seem possible,  as far as I understand. This reflection implementation problem,  if ever solved,   would lead to an exponential speedup of Grover's algorithm.